# How to disable "Sync Apps" and "Open iTunes when this iDevice is connected" without forcing a sync?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipad, ios

I don't want to lose all the stuff on my device. Any way to stop my iPad from automatically syncing with iTunes when connected to the Mac? I turned these features on when I bought it, but in the long run it's not such a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go in to iTunes and go to Preferences -> Devices, and check the box that says Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Edit-> Preferences-> Syncing to disable syncing.